# ASP.NET MVC Users unable to login after password change, and being locked out

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

All,

I have a website that is in use and has several users, using the MySqlMembershipProvider.

We have had a few users that have been locked out (for some reason) and recently I unlocked them and reset the passwords, using the MembershipUser.UnlockUser and MembershipUser.ResetPassword methods.

Now they are definitely marked in the database as Unlocked and the password has been reset, but they still cannot log in.

Does anyone have any ideas why this might happen?

Answer (score 0):

Can any users log in at all? Have them try to clear cache/cookies.

Comment: Users that have not been locked out in the past are able to login, so it is not affecting anyone else.